# Text Detection problems with Google Vision

Tags: ios, swift, google-vision

Not sure what the issues is as my code just stopped working overnight, but the text detection on Google Vision is either returning nil or returning words that are non-existent on the subject.

Here's my request function:

```
func createRequest(with imageBase64: String) {

    let jsonRequest = [
        "requests": [
            "image": [
                "content": imageBase64 ],
            "features": [
                ["type": "TEXT_DETECTION"],
                ["type": "IMAGE_PROPERTIES"]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonRequest)
    var request = URLRequest(url: googleURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

    request.httpBody = jsonData

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let task: URLSessionDataTask = self.URLsession.dataTask(with: request) { (encodedObject, response, error) in
            guard let data = encodedObject, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no data")
                return
            }
            self.analyzeResults(data)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Part of my analyze results function:

```
func analyzeResults(_ data: Data) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data) else { return }
        guard let responseArray = response.responses else { return }
        print(response)
```

Comment: was it working before?

Comment: Yeah it was.  In the end I found the issue; Google puts higher priority on a document_text_detection than on text_detection for the JSON request.  So I just used the former and it's reliable again.